# Why isn't TaskCanceledException stored in Task.Exception property when I execute multiple tasks?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have an application that executes several consequent HTTP requests to RESTful API for each of the different items.

The code I have to handle exceptions from executing these requests is similar to the one described in [Concurrency in C# Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030171.do?cmp=af-code-books-video-product_cj_0636920030171_7489747) by  [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary), recipe 2.4:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var item in items)
{
    tasks.Add(ProcessItemAsync(item));
}
var parentTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
try {
    await parentTask;
} catch {
    var exceptions = parentTask.Exception;
    if (exceptions != null) {
        // log individual exceptions
    }
}
```

While analyzing the logs, I noticed that some of the processing did not result in sending all of the needed requests. However, there were no exceptions recorded in the logs.

When debugging the application, I found that calling one of the endpoints resulted in TaskCanceledException being thrown due to a timeout from Web API. However, `parentTask.Exception` property was `null`, hence, I did not correctly record this exception in the log.

My questions are the following:

- Why isn't TaskCanceledException stored in Task.Exception property?
- Are there any other exceptions that would not be stored in Task.Exception property similar to TaskCanceledException?

Comment: Curiority prompted this question. Why is a timeout causing a cancellation rather than raising a TimeoutException?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get some more info about this by reading [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) about task cancellation, especially this part:

> If you are waiting on a Task that transitions to the Canceled state, a
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException exception (wrapped in an
>   AggregateException exception) is thrown. Note that this exception
>   indicates successful cancellation instead of a faulty situation.
>   Therefore, **the task's Exception property returns null**.

So main point is - task cancellation is an expected thing, it's not a fault. So no reason to set `Exception` property - information about cancellation is already recorded in `Task` state.

Another story is timeout *is* a fault and should not result in task cancellation. On the other hand, pending web request *is* cancelled after some time (after timeout), so that's arguable.

As a workaround, you might inspect all tasks in your `tasks` array to see if they are in cancelled state (`IsCancelled` returns true) and log accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

TaskCanceledException is specially handled by Task.

When TaskCanceledException is not handled within a Task. It simply sets IsCanceled property within the task to true.

Note that if the Task is awaited TaskCanceledException  exception will be thrown, while Task.Exception will remain null.

Comment: `This is only correct when the Task in question is not awaited.`  This isn't quite right.  This always happens, even if the task *is* awaited.  Rather, when you await a canceled `Task`, the `await` throws a `TaskCanceledException` *even though the `Exception` property of the task is `null`* when the task is cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

While it's *possible* to handle aggregate exceptions, I think it's *cleaner* to handle them individually:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var item in items)
  tasks.Add(ProcessItemAndLogExceptionsAsync(item));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

private static async Task ProcessItemAndLogExceptionsAsync(Item item)
{
  try
  {
    await ProcessItemAsync(item);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Log exception
  }
}
```

This way you'll get the `OperationCanceledException`s, too.

Comment: In this case, if I have different `ProcessItemsInOneWay` and `ProcessItemsInAnotherWay` methods, I would have to repeat try/catch/log-exception logic in each of those different methods